# Wireless power transfer power spikes and low efficiency

Tags: transistors, mosfet, wireless, driver

I am working a simulation model of a wireless power transfer in LTspice as presented in the image below.

There are current spikes in the input (V3) that I want to eliminate or reduce.

I have yielded a efficiency of approximately 51%.  How can I increase the sa efficiency to at least 82%?

Presented below are the images from the simulation.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What's your dead band time between Hin and Lin? Please zoom in significantly in time and measure Vgs and Vds across M1 and M2.

Comment: The 51 % efficiency is only a simulation result. I would not be surprised if the real loss of the L2 to L3 wireless power transfer would be much lower than 50 %.

Comment: Beats me. I would suggest being much more concerned with what's happening within a given cycle. Which seems pretty repetitive, so I'm not sure what you intended to show by the fully zoomed-out view. What are the gate signals? What is the load current phase?